# Is it possible to specify function with optional parameter as function argument in Dart2?

Tags: dart

I am using Dart2

What I want to do is to force developer to use callback that accepts no or at most 1 argument.

For example, having following method:

```
    void doYourJob(void onComplete([result])){ //this is what I have tried, buts its wrong - requires ([arg])=> callback
      .... do your job
      onComplete(result);
   }
```

I would like to be able to use that method in two ways eg:

```
doYourJob(()=>doStuff);
```

and

```
   doYourJob((result)=>doMoreStuffWithResult(result));
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. What you are trying to do is not possible.

You want to have a function type which accepts functions taking either zero or one argument. That is, you want to be able to pass a unary function *and* a nullary function.
That is, a function type which is a supertype of both `void Function()` and `void Function(Object)`.

That is not the same as a function type with an optional parameter. Such a function type requires that *all* arguments must be callable *both* with zero and one argument. You cannot pass a pure unary function to that, because that function cannot be called with zero arguments.

There is no *function type* which is a supertype of both `void Function()` and `void Function(Object)`. The nearest supertype is `Function`, which accepts *any* function, not just unary and nullary ones. You can use that, but you lose the type checking.

Comment: This is something I am thinking as well (that I wont be able to do it). I am doing only a runtime check if callback is 1 arg function or none and throw exception if it is otherwise.

Comment: @AjilO. Yes, the approach does not work. Any function argument to `doYourJob` must have an optional first argument. You cannot call it with any of `() => doStuff` or `(result)=>doMoreStuffWithResult(result)`. As such, it doesn't solve the problem that the original poster is trying to solve.

Comment: Accepting `Function` and doing a run-time check is also what `Future.catchError` does&mdash;it can be called with either a unary or a binary function, so it is impossible to type it safely. In Dart 1, this was common. In Dart 2, with its stronger type checking, it is more annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a `typedef`

```dart
typedef Callback = Null Function([String data]);

void doYourJob(Callback onComplete) {
  onComplete('Data');
  onComplete();
}
```

**OR**

You can pass the Function directly

```dart
void doYourJob(Null Function([String data]) onComplete) {
  onComplete('Data');
  onComplete();
}
```

You can call this method like this

```dart
void main() {
  doYourJob(([String data]) {
    print('DATA: $data');
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you took the issue from the wrong side. I want to be able to pass callback like `doYourJob(()=>...)` and `doYourJob((res)=>...)` but I want to have an compile time error on attempt to `doYourJob((res,sum)=>...)` So execution code does not have to be elegant, but usage of API should. In other words I want to mimic little behavior of typescript in that manner - and still be able to do proper invocations of callback. (as I cannot use `callback(res)` when actual callback is `(()=>...)`

Comment: Right now, I am using just `Function` as arg type and before invocation i am checking if `callback is Function(dynamic)` to know how to invoke callback. This works, but does not give me any type control I would like to have here as well.

Comment: @Antoniossss Maybe I am being too dumb to understand your question here... But isn't this syntax what you're looking for? `doYourJob(([_]) => /*Do whatever you want here*/  print(''));`

Comment: I think I am partially getting your point. But you could still do this right?
`doYourJob(([result]) => result == null ? print('Do something') : print('Do something else'));`

Comment: It will work, but that is exaclty the opposite what I wanted to do. I think that Irn got the idea correct and it is simply not possible. My goal was to make API to be little bit flexible and easy to read/write with the benefit of type controll to some extent.